# Relation of drift velocity and electric field?

Tags: drift, electric-field, velocity

[image]

So I attached the standard derivation of the relationship between drift velocity and electric field.

My problem is:

Tau=s/Vd, where s is the mean free path of the electron. Substituting this into the Vd=(...) equation, we should get that E is actually proportional to (Vd)^2. Tau is not actually a constant as it's implied but it's dependent on the velocity. But also this can't really be true as it would contradict Ohm's law which suggests a linear relationship between E and Vd. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You assumed you have material where electrons are stopped after they have flied distance s and start immediately again to increase their speed due the electric field which causes certain constant acceleration a=eE/m. You based your calculations on a known elementary mechanics formula 2s=aT^2 where T is the duration of the constant acceleration.

As a consequence you assumed a material where the drift velocity is proportional with the square root of the electric field. An experimentally found law by Georg Ohm tells that in metals and other common conductors those quantities are directly proportional (assuming there's such things as electrons).

There's no contradiction. Your assumption of the free path length as a material constant isn't valid for metals and other common conductors. The assumption of average free flight duration between collisions as a material constant fits better. It's discussed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model That model gives the linear Vd vs E dependence although it's far too simple to predict right many other phenomenas.

"What am I missing?" Nothing. You have met the same as scientists which try to investigate the real world. They make a math assumption how something works and see the result doesn't fit into the experimental data. If no errors can be found the assumption is simply wrong, a better assumption is needed. This is how the physics has gradually developed.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you. Since then I found the following explanation:
[image]

Comment: If your going to post this, you need a link or reference to the source, otherwise it's plagiarism, and that violates guidelines. Please provide a source, please also make the picture readable